# What is a good example to show that the government should not go against its laws for the greater good of the population

Tags: kant, utilitarianism

For example, the FBI unlawfully hacks into everyone's computer and catches 10,000 terrorists in doing so, causing happiness to the general population.

What kind of counter example can I give to show that government should not go against its laws for the greater good of its population?

In essence, I want to show that this maxim is not fit to become a universal law, but I can't find a good counter example

Comment: Your second and third paragraphs are fundamentally different. Also, maybe you should reword each as separate questions to ask *whether* kantianism or utilitarianism is fundamentally opposed to violating laws to pursue seemingly noble ends.

Comment: It's clear what he's asking, he's asking if liberalism is logically coherent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If unlawfully hacking goes unchecked for catching 10,000 terrorists, then whatever control of power that should do the checking would be shown impotent. Therefore the heart of the issue is that we lose the ability to control such power, leaving little or nothing to prevent them from abusing it. What's to stop them from hacking into everyone's computer to maliciously obtain information, for example, about bank accounts or other private matters of law-abiding citizens?

> "Those who would give up essential Liberty, to purchase a little
>   temporary Safety, deserve neither Liberty nor Safety." (Benjamin
>   Franklin)

Comment: You could also cite Joseph McCarthy era Red Scare.